# Use PrimeFaces blockUI on navigation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I need an answer to exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462190/how-to-use-primefaces-3-5-blockui-block-all-page-playout-when-click-pmenu-in) question posted in 2013 please.

I have a PrimeFaces `menuitem` with a `url` attribute that calls an xhtml, that 'defines' content to go into a `layoutUnit`. When clicked, the entire page doesn't reload, just the layout unit.

How do I display a PrimeFaces Extensions `blockUI` component when the `menuItem` is clicked?

I've tried:

```
<p:menuitem value="Users" url="/users.xhtml" onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()"/>
```

where the `blockUIWidget` is:

```
<pe:blockUI widgetVar="blockUIWidget">
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:graphicImage library="images" name="loading.gif"/>
  <h:outputText value="Loading"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Note, this widget works as expected from a `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" action="submit" onstart="PF('blockUIWidget').block()" oncomplete="PF('blockUIWidget').unblock()"/>
```

Comment: did you try to `rendred` your `blockUI` ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight thank you. What do you mean by `rendred`? I've updated the question to show that the widget works as expected from a `commandButton`. I just need it to work the same on a `menuitem`, or perhaps a suggestion of something else I can use to show the user that the app has acknowledged the click, and we are navigating to the required screen.

Comment: it works like this `rendred ="#{managedBean.someCondition}"` if it's true it will be invisible try it with true and false you will see the difference

Comment: In your case change the someCondition when you click the menuitem

Comment: Does `<p:menuitem value="Users" url="/users.xhtml" onstart="alert('start')" oncomplete="alert('complete')"/> ` work? If not, it is not blokui related but a generic issue

Comment: @YagamiLight `<pe:blockUI widgetVar="blockUIWidget" rendered="true">...` doesn't display the widget. @Kukeltje thank you too. Using your suggestion, no alert boxes are displayed when clicking the `menuitem`. I tried changing `url` to `outcome` and using `ajax=true` with no luck. The PrimeFaces 5.2 manual has `onstart` and `onsuccess` as valid attributes of `menuitem`. I tried PrimeFaces 5.3 and 6 as well.

Comment: FYI, I've ditched ``BlockUI`` altogether and gone with

``<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>``

in the header of the template